# Simple cross-domain iframe postMessage works in jsfiddle but not locally

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to work with an `iframe` on another domain, and I got stuck at the "Hello World!" stage.

I have two files, served over two static servers. I refer to those files over two different domains and different ports.

#### `http://localhost:8080/index.html`

```
<iframe id="target" src="http://hocallost:8081/iframe.html" frameborder="1"></iframe>

<script>
    var target = document.getElementById('target');
    target.contentWindow.postMessage('hello', '*');
</script>
```

#### `http://hocallost:8081/iframe.html`

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('message', function receiveMessage(message) {
        console.log(message);
        document.body.textContent = "Hello World!";
    }, false);
</script>
```

Now, locally, the message event handler isn't even firing. I have no message, console.log is not invoked and my breakpoint isn't breaking.

When I took `index.html`'s source and pasted it into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), it works! The event fires and I get the Hello World.

Now, I obviously won't be able to rely on JSFiddle on my production application, what am I doing wrong? What am I missing here? Does JSFiddle do something behind the scenes that I'm failing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to wait for the target iframe to be loaded.

```
var target = document.getElementById('target');
target.onload = function(){
    target.contentWindow.postMessage('hello', '*')
}
```

Note : don't forget to replace '*' with the relevant origin when deploying your code.